# How to get this result when multiplying 1d-array by 2d-array?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I am struggling to figure out, how the output is calculated can you please explain?

I have this

```
w=np.array([[50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
       [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74]])
```

multiplied by this array :

c = np.array([3267. , 3375.9, 3484.8, 3630., 3740.])

the output is:

`array([1050885., 1068309., 1085733., 1103157., 1120581.])`

Comment: The output of `w * c` isn't that though...

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. The shape of the product is `(5, 5)` instead of `(5,)`.

Comment: It's close to `w.T @ c`, ∆ ~ [4977.5, 5051.2, 5124.9, 5198.6, 5272.3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grasping at straws because it feels like there's not enough information to solve this. But, here is one way to get the result:

```
import numpy as np

w = np.array(
    [
        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
        [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
        [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
        [70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
    ]
)
c = np.array([3267.0, 3375.9, 3484.8, 3630.0, 3740.0])

r = w.T @ c
d = [4977.5 + i * 73.7 for i in range(5)]

result = r - d
```

`result`:

```
array([1050885., 1068309., 1085733., 1103157., 1120581.])
```

Comment: Nice catch of `np.diff([1050885., 1068309., 1085733., 1103157., 1120581.] - w.T @ c)`! `w.T @ c - (4977.5 + np.arange(5) * 73.7)` for a `numpy` solution. If I had to guess, I would say this is the first iteration of a gradient descent calculation.